# Excel VLookup and List

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to list all of the unique occurrences of one cell on a table and then list them.

```
TABLE 1

PLACES      WEEK
| Place 1 | Week 2 |
| Place 1 | Week 2 |
| Place 1 | Week 2 |
| Place 1 | Week 3 |
| Place 2 | Week 2 | 
| Place 2 | Week 3 |
| Place 3 | Week 2 |
| Place 4 | Week 3 |
| Place 4 | Week 3 |
| Place 4 | Week 3 |
```

So on another sheet I want a list of all Places that are in week 2 but I only want one occurrence of each. The result being from this that I would get.

```
| Place 1 |
| Place 2 |
| Place 3 |
```

but not place 4 on my list.

Is this possible with a formula.

Thanks,

Comment: why not place 4? In your example it is in week 2 as well... Please elaborate or correct

Comment: you dont look like a newbee, but still: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: @K_B Yes typo there should be no occurrence of Week 2 in Place 4

Comment: Not possible with a formula.  You need a Pivot table or a 'SELECT DISTINCT...' query.

Comment: @Stewbob Anything is possible. I've nearly got it

Comment: What have you got that you nearly got it? Please amend the question with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you ok with spaces this is the first thing to come to mind

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!B1= 2,$A$1:A1 <>Sheet1!A1),Sheet1!A1, "")
```

When you enter it, enter as array (Ctrl + Shift + Enter), make sure you get "{}" Surrounding the formula then drag down. And make sure to start in the second row of the column.